# ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

I was installing django channels and I got an error that twisted was not installed. I tried installing it after downloading the package from here `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted`. But now I am getting this error..

```
ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Is there a way to install it properly in windows 10. I am using python 3.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` is a wheel for Python version 3.9, 64 bit, Windows. Error "is not a supported wheel on this platform" means that either your Python is not 3.9 or is not 64-bit (even if Windows is 64-bit Python still can be 32-bit).

Check version:

```
python --version
```

and check bitness:

```
python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are using cp39 package and your system have Python 3.8
cp39 stands for CPython 3.9(this wheel file os for python 3.9.X series), for your system you must install wheel file for 3.8 python series.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30718859)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it downloading the win32 version though I have a x64 architecture, here the link for download, you have to download the following wheel **Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl**:

*[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)*